# ¿Cómo transmitir vídeo a través de internet?

Tags: c#, wpf, socket

Estoy diseñando una aplicación en c# utilizando WPF y me estoy metiendo por primera vez al mundo de los sockets.

Actualmente tengo hecho un prototipo en el que voy recibiendo capturas de pantalla de mi servidor y las voy mostrando en el cliente en un control `<Image>` simulando que es un vídeo, el problema que tengo es que se muestran muy pocas imágenes por segundo (en torno a 12-15).

He estado revisando en el programa qué es lo que más tiempo tarda en realizarse y es sin duda la captura de pantalla, la cual tarda en torno a 0,07 segundos en realizarse, la clase que utilizo para realizar la captura es la siguiente:

```
class ScreenRecorder : IDisposable
{
    private Bitmap screenBMP;
    private Graphics graphics;

    public ScreenRecorder()
    {
        screenBMP = new Bitmap((int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBMP);
    }

    public byte[] ScreenToBytes()
    {
        byte[] data;
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenBMP.Size);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            screenBMP.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        graphics.Dispose();
        screenBMP.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de optimizar este proceso o de si existe alguna librería para capturar directamente el vídeo en un `VideoFrame` o en un array de bytes. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: El concepto que buscas es [transmisión de video](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming), que si bien tiene su complejidad, hay muchas aplicaciones para eso, como [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.es-MX.html). La solución consiste en instalar el software en el servidor y configurar el origen del video. Incluso existen cámaras que ya tienen integrada la función de streaming. Del lado del cliente, ya sea con un plugin reproductor o con una etiqueta html `<video>`. Hacerlo por librería desde cero será mucho más complicado, el mismo VLC es un framework y tiene la librería `libVLC`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @Sal, me acabas de abrir los ojos y voy a continuar mi investigación por ese lado.

Comment: Tal vez lo que quieres hacer ya lo tengas aquí: https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin